# Why is my voltmeter output incorrect

Tags: batteries, basic, voltmeter

So I'm completely new to electrical design. I thought I'd try out the most basic experiment I could think of. Here I hooked up two AA batteries to a breadboard along with a 10 K resistor. When I attempt to measure the voltage drop across the resistor by touching the leads to both ends I get an output of .1 V. If I understand correctly the output should be about 3 V. Is there something I'm doing wrong?
Here's a picture of my set up.

[image]

Comment: That switch position looks like a battery tester, not a voltmeter. Multimeter appling some load. Read the manual.

Comment: Right, set it to the "20" setting in the Voltage region (straight up).

Answer (score 3):

Your meter doesn't seem to be set to dc voltage. That's the yellow area on your dial, right above the "off" position, I'd guess from as many pixels as I get.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this clearer photo I found of your meter:

[image]

You have it set to the 1.5V battery tester mode. You need to set it to the voltage measurement mode, as others have pointed out. The DC voltage range is at the top, going between 2 and 600 volts. You need to choose the next range higher than the expected voltage. In your case, you're expecting 3V and the next highest range is 20. Set it to the 20V setting and I think you'll see what you expect.

Comment: I actually did try that at first. I had it set to 20 V and it still reported .1 V. I even tried switching out the batteries and resistor (to a 2K resistor) and it still reported .1 V.  I double-checked right now and am still getting .1 V as an output. 

Maybe my meter is malfunctioning. It's not brand new and I haven't paid much mind to proper maintenance .

Comment: It's possible the internal fuse is blown. What happens if you put the probes across a known-good battery? Does it give you a reading?